# How to install 100 server's less effort?

Tags: installation, server

I am trying to install 100's of ubuntu servers,they needs  servers(apache/memcached) to be configured and they needs some other packages(only 5 or 6) to be installed. what is the best way for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for some degree of automation on bare metal installation, there's [Orchestra](https://launchpad.net/orchestra). For cloud, specifically the Amazon EC2, you can use [juju](https://juju.ubuntu.com/) for completely automated deployment.

Orchestra's Launchpad page is quite lacking on information and details, as of writing this answer. This [Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72772/what-is-orchestra-and-how-do-i-use-it/72846#72846) will explain, in brief, how it works and links to appropriate documents to get started on using it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Custom Ubuntu Server iso : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization
with a PXE install server : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallServer