# What is Orchestra, and how do I use it?

Tags: server, orchestra

Writing [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72694/how-to-install-100-servers-less-effert/72707#72707), I realized I do not know anything about [Orchestra](https://launchpad.net/orchestra). There's no link to any website or documentation on their Launchpad page.

Can anyone familiar with it explain how it works and how to use it? I read Orchestra is going to be integrated into [juju](https://juju.ubuntu.com) for easily setting up bare metal systems, so I'm assuming Orchestra works in a similar manner.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Here](http://voices.canonical.com/shang.wu/2011/08/31/oneiric-ubuntu-orchestra-server-provision-server-setup/) is some basic information and a more detailed [introduction by Dustin Kirkland](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/08/formal-introduction-to-ubuntu-orchestra.html).

Basically, the Ubuntu orchestra server consist of the following components:

1. Provisioning Server -> Cobbler
2. Monitoring Server -> Nagios
3. Management Server -> Juju
4. Logging Server -> Rsyslog

Cobbler is a Linux installation server that allows for rapid setup of network installation environments.

Nagios monitors large deployments to ensure systems, applications, services and business processes are functioning properly.

[Juju](https://juju.ubuntu.com/) was previously codenamed Ensemble. Through the use of charms, which describe services and their dependencies and interfaces, juju provides shareable, re-usable and repeatable expressions of DevOps best practices. Check out [this](http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2011/10/17/#ubuntu-classroom.html#t17:01) Ubuntu Open Week Session for an intro to Juju.

Rsyslog is an enhanced syslogd supporting, among others, MySQL, PostgreSQL, failover log destinations, syslog/tcp, fine grain output format control, high precision timestamps, queued operations and the ability to filter on any message part.

Quoting from the [Ubuntu Wiki page about Orchestra](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/Orchestra):

> A collection of what we think are the best free software services for
>   provisioning, deploying, hosting, managing, and orchestrating
>   enterprise data center infrastructure services, by, with, and for the
>   Ubuntu Server. Orchestra, enables users to quickly deploy a solution
>   in the datacentre. Instead of manually setting up a complex network
>   installation environment, users can leverage Orchestra to rapidly
>   deploy new servers in production using the best open-source tools. The
>   process is standardised and fully automated, minimising manual
>   intervention and ensuring consistency.

If you scroll down on the above mentioned Ubuntu Wiki page, you will find two links for a tutorial on setting up an Ubuntu-based Orchestra server in the safe confines of Virtualbox. For convenience, here are the links:

[Deploy Orchestra server fleets part 1](http://cloud.ubuntu.com/2011/09/oneiric-server-deploy-server-fleets-p1/)

[Deploy Orchestra server fleets part 2](http://cloud.ubuntu.com/2011/09/oneiric-server-deploy-server-fleets-p2/)

Comment: [This blog post by Dustin Kirkland](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/08/formal-introduction-to-ubuntu-orchestra.html) may be interesting, too.